Levis, parabolics and Bruhat-Tits over Henselian local rings
Let $(R,m)$ be a Henselian local ring with algebraically closed or finite residue field $k$ and fraction field $F$. For example, we may work with $R=W(\mathbb F_p^{alg})$.
The paper "Reductive Group Schemes" https://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/luminysga3.pdf by B. Conrad stuidies reductive group schemes by dynamic methods. Let $G$ be a connected smooth affine group scheme over $R$. We know

(Theorem 3.2.6 and Corollary 3.2.7.) Assume $G$ is reductive. Then the base change of $G$ to some finite 'etale extension of $R$ will admit a maximal torus. If $G_k$ admits a maximal torus, then $G$ has a maximal torus.

(Theorem 4.1.7.) For any cocharacter $\lambda: \mathbb G_m \to G$, we may define closed smooth subgroup schemes $P_G(\lambda)=Z_G(\lambda)U_G(\lambda)$ (with connected fibers) of $G$ by dynamic methods. The Lie algebra of $P_G(\lambda)$ is the subalgebra of $\mathrm{Lie} G$ contaning all non-negative weight spaces (for the $\mathbb G_m$-action). We know $Z_G(\lambda)=P_G(\lambda) \cap P_G(-\lambda)$, and $U_G(\lambda)$ has unipotent fibers. If $G$ is reductive, then $P_G(\lambda)$ is a parabolic group scheme of $G$ with Levi factor $Z_G(\lambda)$.

(Proposition 5.2.3 and Remark 5.2.4) Assume $G$ is reductive. If $G$ admits a maximal torus $T$, then any parabolic group scheme $Q$ of $G$ is of the form $P_G(\lambda)$ for a cocharacter $\lambda: \mathbb G_m \to T$.

(Page 180, after Cor 5.4.8) "In particular, if $S$ is a connected affine scheme then every parabolic Ssubgroup $Q$ in a reductive $S$-group $G$ admits a dynamic description because such $Q$ always admit a Levi $S$-subgroup $L$." Namely, $(Q, L)$ is of the form $(P_G(\lambda), Z_G(\lambda)$ for some $\lambda : \mathbb G_m \to G$ over $S$.


I am interested in generalizations of these results.

(bad reduction) Let $G$ be a parahoric group scheme of its generic fiber $G_F$. Is there a classification of parabolic subgroup scheme $Q$ of $G$ by dynamic methods (i.e. $G_s/Q_s$ is proper for any geometric point $s$ of $R$)? Note the special fiber $G_s$ is not reductive in general.

(Explicit descriptions of Levi). Assume $G$ is reductive. We know the Lie algebra of the reductive Levi $Z_G(\lambda)$ as zero weight spaces of $\mathrm{Lie} G$. However, the Lie algebra does not determine the Levi group. Do we know how to desribe the isogeny type of $Z_G(\lambda)$ e.g. what is the center of $Z_G(\lambda)$?

(Centralizer of tours) Given a torus $S \leq G$, is the centralizer $C_G(S)$ a Levi subgroup of $G$. This is true over an algebraically closed field, see Proposition 1.22 of "Representations of Finite Groups of Lie Type" by François Digne and Jean Michel.


An example is $G=Spin(L)$ for a quadratic lattice $L$ over $R$.

It looks like the last two questions are just over a field. For the second one, what kind of answer do you want? For example, if $\lambda$ factors through a maximal torus $T$, then the center is the kernel of the roots of $T$ which pair trivially with $\lambda$. On the other hand, the center of the derived group of $Z_G(\lambda)$ is more complicated. For the third question, the answer is no: if $G$ is split and $S$ is a non-split maximal torus, then $S$ is its own centralizer and is not a Levi. (It would have to be the Levi of a Borel, but all maximal tori in Borels are split in this case.)
